# Pythonのdataframeで、各時刻ごとにデータをグループ化して相関を計算する方法

Tags: python, python3, pandas, google-colaboratory

#### 背景

時系列データの分析を行おうと思っております。
各時刻ごとにseriesを作ってcorrを出そうとしているのですが、NaNになってうまく参照できません。（おそらくデータフレームのインデックスが悪さをしているものと思われます）

row_dataは以下で指定したデータフレームです。
ドル円の価格データ、時刻（UTC）を格納してます。

```
row_data = pd.DataFrame()
row_data.index = pd.to_datetime( a_time ,unit='s' )
```

以下はrow_dataの中身です。
（黒塗りしている部分は学習させようとしているとある特徴量です、秘密となって申し訳ありません）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 欲しいもの

お尋ねしたいことは、インデックスを置き換えて各時間帯ごとのドル円の動きの相関を計算する方法です。

相関を計算したい背景としては、以下の二つがございます。

1. 「この時間帯は売られている傾向にある」「この時間帯は価格がほとんど動かない」といった時間帯別の動きを分析したい
2. 「この時間帯で売りだったら、同じ日の別の時間帯でも売りだな」といった同じ日のプライスアクションの推定に使いたい

時間帯別に分けるために、あえてrow_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == ？？')としてmodを計算しております。

もし叶うなら、price0 ～ price23という指定方法もスマートな記法でないので直したいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

以下、問題のコード

```
price0 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 0')["price"]
price1 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 1')["price"]
price2 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 2')["price"]
price3 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 3')["price"]
price4 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 4')["price"]
price5 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 5')["price"]
price6 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 6')["price"]
price7 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 7')["price"]
price8 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 8')["price"]
price9 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 9')["price"]
price10 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 10')["price"]
price11 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 11')["price"]
price12 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 12')["price"]
price13 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 13')["price"]
price14 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 14')["price"]
price15 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 15')["price"]
price16 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 16')["price"]
price17 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 17')["price"]
price18 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 18')["price"]
price19 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 19')["price"]
price20 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 20')["price"]
price21 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 21')["price"]
price22 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 22')["price"]
price23 = row_data.query('time.dt.hour % 24 == 23')["price"]

timedata = pd.DataFrame()
timedata["price0"] = price0
timedata["price1"] = price1
timedata["price2"] = price2
timedata["price3"] = price3
timedata["price4"] = price4
timedata["price5"] = price5
timedata["price6"] = price6
timedata["price7"] = price7
timedata["price8"] = price8
timedata["price9"] = price9
timedata["price10"] = price10
timedata["price11"] = price11
timedata["price12"] = price12
timedata["price13"] = price13
timedata["price14"] = price14
timedata["price15"] = price15
timedata["price16"] = price16
timedata["price17"] = price17
timedata["price18"] = price18
timedata["price19"] = price19
timedata["price20"] = price20
timedata["price21"] = price21
timedata["price22"] = price22
timedata["price23"] = price23

timedata.corr()
```

---

#### 追記1

出力結果の画像：
下図参照。対話型の環境で　timedata.corr()　と一文のみ叩いた結果です。
（Google Colab使用）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 追記2

以下のコマンドを実行した結果を貼ります

```
print(timedata.dtypes)

price0     float64
price1     float64
price2     float64
price3     float64
price4     float64
price5     float64
price6     float64
price7     float64
price8     float64
price9     float64
price10    float64
price11    float64
price12    float64
price13    float64
price14    float64
price15    float64
price16    float64
price17    float64
price18    float64
price19    float64
price20    float64
price21    float64
price22    float64
price23    float64
dtype: object
```

```
print(timedata.head())

                         price0  price1  price2  ...  price21  price22  price23
2020-02-14 00:04:53  107.592214     NaN     NaN  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN
2020-02-15 00:04:03  108.605378     NaN     NaN  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN
2020-02-16 00:03:05  104.148801     NaN     NaN  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN
2020-02-17 00:04:56  104.670248     NaN     NaN  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN
2020-02-18 00:02:49  102.353737     NaN     NaN  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

#### 追記３

oriri様のコマンドを試したところ、同じく望む結果が得られました。ありがとうございました！

```
#print(timedata.head())
row_data['hour'] = row_data.time.dt.hour; row_data['idx'] = row_data.groupby(['hour']).cumcount(); t_df = row_data.pivot(index='idx', columns='hour', values='price');
t_df

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
hour    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
idx                                                                                             
0   101.466057  100.736002  100.613901  100.550625  100.040697  99.336579   99.565088   99.802942   99.615076   101.952404  101.723916  101.457435  101.356704  101.084811  101.348601  100.937615  100.536535  98.637930   99.698924   100.006355  99.449476   99.796364   99.678555   100.546013
1   99.220459   98.619188   99.204835   98.989250   99.203553   99.896366   99.901667   99.571404   99.957212   100.023744  100.018346  99.273064   98.484291   98.480936   97.399156   98.063215   98.525274   98.860104   98.408608   98.352853   98.606536   98.449535   98.447897   98.291042
2   103.406300  102.998132  103.018872  103.494632  103.299935  103.028391  103.057140  102.373089  102.546459  99.522024   99.020597   99.059842   99.045411   98.607208   98.365976   98.904512   100.218330  100.846127  101.373579  101.751316  102.223781  103.480178  102.521503  103.394961
3   98.220579   98.334953   98.081711   97.962889   97.777987   97.718834   97.682106   98.161300   98.175861   103.356480  103.129635  103.046662  103.508397  102.966195  103.054323  103.265744  103.266786  103.617703  103.332107  103.747723  103.449175  102.776059  97.755187   98.859030
4   98.042543   97.974252   98.381533   98.380449   98.831023   98.775352   98.675039   98.685778   98.556643   97.510241   98.027801   98.031343   97.685927   97.426084   97.828133   97.839126   97.759634   98.404448   97.237050   97.201989   97.516242   97.767862   98.191744   98.138238
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

Comment: > 各時刻ごとにseriesを作ってcorrを出そうとしているのですが、NaNになってうまく参照できません。（おそらくデータフレームのインデックスが悪さをしているものと思われます）　　その現象はコードの何処で発生しているのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。現象としては、google colabを使って「timedata.corr()」と打ち込んだ時に発生したものです。詳細については↑に追記しました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: timedataの中身が分かると原因が分かるかもしれません。timedata.dtypesとtimedata.head()の結果を掲載できますでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。timedata.dtypesとtimedata.head()のprint結果を記載いたしました。

Comment: 期待してる DataFrameがよくわからないのだけど, こういうものですか？`df['hour'] = df.time.dt.hour;
df['idx'] = df.groupby(['hour']).cumcount();
td_df = df.pivot(index='idx', columns='hour', values='price');`

Comment: price1以降の値がNaNですね。元データが分からないので原因は分かりませんが。また、print(timedata.head())の結果には日時のインデックスがあるようですが、質問のコードでそのようなデータフレームになりますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。追記しました。

Comment: merino様＞　print(timedata.head())の結果を最新化しました。インデックスに日時の情報があるのは　row_data.index = pd.to_datetime( a_time ,unit='s' )　で指定してあるからです。またrow_dataの中身も追加しました

Comment: oriri様＞　申し訳ありません。全くおなじコマンドをたたいたのですがエラーを吐き出してしまいました。エラーログごと追加編集いたしました。

Comment: @Rich-4-coding すみません, `row_data` を元にして, corr() 直前の DataFrame に, これで作ることができるかどうか, ということでした。`timedata` ではなく `row_data` に対して行ってみてください

Comment: oriri様＞　コメントありがとうございます。row_dataに先ほどのコマンドを試してみたところ望む結果が得られました！追記しておきました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[バックテスティングの改善に役立つForexヒストリカルデータの検索方法](https://forextester.jp/data/datasources) から 「USDJPY 2001年1月 - 2021年02月28日」(`USDJPY.zip`)をダウンロードして、2020 年のデータを抽出します。

```sh
$ unzip -p USDJPY.zip | grep -P 'USDJPY,2020\d{4},\d{2}0000,' > 2020_USDJPY_hourly.txt
```

`pandas.read_csv` で読み込んで、[pandas.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) で `time_data`(dataframe)を作成します。

```py
import pandas as pd

row_data = pd.read_csv(
  '2020_USDJPY_hourly.txt',
  header=None, usecols=[1, 2, 6], names=('date', 'time_', 'price'),
  parse_dates={'time': [0, 1]}
)

time_data = pd.pivot_table(
  row_data,
  index=row_data.time.dt.date,
  columns=row_data.time.dt.hour, values='price')

print(time_data.head(10))
=>
time            0       1       2       3       4   ...      19      20      21      22      23
time                                                ...                                        
2020-01-01     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  108.67
2020-01-02  108.71  108.68  108.65  108.66  108.70  ...  108.51  108.53  108.54  108.56  108.53
2020-01-03  108.53  108.39  108.19  108.05  108.17  ...  108.04  108.00  108.09     NaN     NaN
2020-01-05     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  107.79
2020-01-06  107.96  108.06  107.93  108.02  108.04  ...  108.35  108.44  108.42  108.36  108.36
2020-01-07  108.40  108.41  108.42  108.46  108.46  ...  108.53  108.52  108.54  108.44  108.44
2020-01-08  107.99  107.85  108.01  108.38  108.35  ...  109.12  109.22  109.02  109.11  109.06
2020-01-09  109.02  109.17  109.23  109.18  109.18  ...  109.44  109.50  109.49  109.51  109.46
2020-01-10  109.48  109.48  109.53  109.52  109.52  ...  109.52  109.51  109.49     NaN     NaN
2020-01-12     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  109.52

[10 rows x 24 columns]
```

このデータフレームに `pandas.corr()` を適用します。

```
print(time_data.corr())
=>
time        0         1         2         3   ...        20        21        22        23
time                                          ...                                        
0     1.000000  0.998382  0.994957  0.994449  ...  0.960008  0.959208  0.966937  0.969895
1     0.998382  1.000000  0.996297  0.995821  ...  0.963861  0.963568  0.969982  0.972866
2     0.994957  0.996297  1.000000  0.999167  ...  0.964468  0.965223  0.971737  0.974439
3     0.994449  0.995821  0.999167  1.000000  ...  0.965086  0.966191  0.972655  0.975659
4     0.993758  0.995235  0.998780  0.999420  ...  0.967782  0.969106  0.975706  0.978260
5     0.992907  0.994802  0.997218  0.997928  ...  0.971550  0.972953  0.977688  0.980040
6     0.991715  0.993290  0.996010  0.996716  ...  0.971927  0.973570  0.977406  0.979626
7     0.991353  0.993005  0.995414  0.996074  ...  0.972183  0.974012  0.978173  0.980512
8     0.989586  0.991248  0.994801  0.995423  ...  0.974502  0.976031  0.980188  0.982476
9     0.989127  0.990321  0.992793  0.993327  ...  0.978027  0.979207  0.982307  0.984337
10    0.987345  0.988976  0.990808  0.991402  ...  0.980707  0.981875  0.983737  0.985517
11    0.984182  0.986479  0.988754  0.989333  ...  0.982878  0.984315  0.986281  0.987737
12    0.981294  0.983719  0.985908  0.986504  ...  0.985817  0.986936  0.988243  0.989538
13    0.979470  0.981863  0.983568  0.984141  ...  0.987895  0.988728  0.989782  0.990849
14    0.977615  0.980218  0.980394  0.980647  ...  0.991935  0.992034  0.993162  0.994264
15    0.974396  0.976925  0.977749  0.977743  ...  0.994198  0.993840  0.994864  0.995547
16    0.970320  0.972823  0.972006  0.972138  ...  0.995696  0.994675  0.995603  0.995509
17    0.966733  0.969695  0.970327  0.970445  ...  0.997612  0.996696  0.997372  0.997141
18    0.965993  0.969202  0.969905  0.970339  ...  0.998055  0.997251  0.997702  0.997614
19    0.961176  0.965142  0.966406  0.966674  ...  0.999221  0.998561  0.998875  0.998385
20    0.960008  0.963861  0.964468  0.965086  ...  1.000000  0.998917  0.999069  0.998543
21    0.959208  0.963568  0.965223  0.966191  ...  0.998917  1.000000  0.999632  0.999018
22    0.966937  0.969982  0.971737  0.972655  ...  0.999069  0.999632  1.000000  0.999341
23    0.969895  0.972866  0.974439  0.975659  ...  0.998543  0.999018  0.999341  1.000000

[24 rows x 24 columns]
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！まさに求めているような回答でした！こちらを参考にコードを書き直してみます！

Answer (score 1):

問題の処理は, 時間ごとにデータを一つ一つ取り出し, それを column として DataFrameを構築しようとしているようですが, 最初のステップで index が決定されているようです

```py
timedata = pd.DataFrame()
timedata["price0"] = price0
```

indexは, 特に何も指定していなければ行の indexであり, 最初の追加時点の indexは `0, 24, 48 …`  と続くはずです。
これに続けて, 別の時間帯のデータを追加しようとしても, indexがマッチせず, そのためデータが存在しないままになるはず

この(一つ一つの)データ追加時に, (それぞれ) reset_index などで indexを割り振れば追加可能なはず
(ただし, すべての時間帯のデータ数が同じ場合)

---

これらをもっと簡単にするには, Pandas らしく, ベクトルでデータ処理することです

```py
row_data['hour'] = row_data.time.dt.hour
row_data['idx'] = row_data.groupby(['hour']).cumcount()
timedata = row_data.pivot(index='idx', columns='hour', values='price')
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！（反応遅くなり申し訳ございません）
`row_data['hour'] = row_data.time.dt.hour; row_data['idx'] = row_data.groupby(['hour']).cumcount(); timedata = row_data.pivot(index='idx', columns='hour', values='price')`
が一番書きたかった形に近かったので大変参考になりました。遅まきながら感謝申し上げます。